# How to access a Dictionary values within a list by a class object?

Tags: c#, list, object, dictionary

I've a class like as below:

```
public class Source
{     
    ...
    ...
    public List<Dictionary<int, int>> blanks { get; set; }
}
```

I've created an object of this and a Dictionary for it. I filled 'dic' Dictionary. Then, I add this dic to the blanks list.

```
Source src = new Source();
Dictionary<int, int> dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();
dic.Add(30, 50);
dic.Add(40, 60);
src.blanks.Add(dic);
```

And I try to access these 'Key' and 'Value' elements. But, I can't.

```
int a = src.blanks[0].Key; 
int b = src.blanks[0].Value;
```

What can I do to access these elements?

Thanks.

Comment: You are forgetting the index of the dictionary. Simply said as an example `src.blanks[0][Key]`

Answer (score 2):

`src.blanks[0]` is a whole dictionary, not a single `KeyValuePair<int,int>`. That is why you cannot access a `.Key` or `.Value` on it - there are potentially many keys, and many values associated with them.

You can access all key-value pairs in a dictionary at position zero by enumerating them, like this:

```
foreach (var kvp in src.blanks[0]) {
    int a = kvp.Key;
    int b = kvp.Value;
    Console.WriteLine("Key:{0} Value:{1}", a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`blanks[0]` returns a `Dictionary<int, int>`, you need to specify key of your item.

```
src.blanks[0][key]
```

Or loop through your values:

```
foreach(var pair in src.blanks[0])
{
    int currentKey = pair.Key;
    int currentValue = pair.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access **a dictionary** in the list which has no `Key` property. The `Keyvaluepairs` **in** a dictionary have keys.

So assuming you want to look into the first dictionary in the list:

```
Dictionary<int, int> dict = s.blanks[0];
// lookup 30:
int value = dict[30]; // 40
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the value you should first  index the list and then index the dictionary

to get  value

```
int b = (src.blanks[0])[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like the following:

```
var listItem = src.blanks[0];
var dictionaryItem = listItem[0];

var a = dictionaryItem.Key;
var b = dictionaryItem.Value;
```

Nevertheless, i advice you to get rid of those "nested generics" `List<Dictionary<..,..>`. You won't be able to distinguish what kind of object you're dealing with if you use these nested structs.
Use other structs that better represent your business logic. For example, you could derive your own class from List